# Не могли бы мне объяснить

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему не работает первый вариант (или что я делаю не так?)
И как работает третий ?

```py
my_list = ['foo', 'bar']
my_list1 = my_list.copy()
my_list2 = my_list.copy()
numbers = list(range(5))

my_list.append(num for num in numbers)

for num in numbers:
    my_list1.append(num)

my_list2.extend(numbers)

print(my_list)
print(my_list1)
print(my_list2)
```

результат первого способа:

```
['foo', 'bar', <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0059ACB0>] ['foo', 'bar', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Работает именно так как должно - добавляет генератор в качестве очередного элемента списка.

Comment: Это типичное недорзумение начинающего изучать Пайтон, списочные(iterable) данные зачастую формируются в виде генераторов и это  по началу сильно сбивает с толку. Объяснение этой концепции обычно идет уже под конец обучения до которой зачастую начинающие еще не дошли. Ведь и range(5) - тоже возвращает генератор но конструкция list(range(5)) преобразует генератор в список.  И вы тоже изменив my_list.append(num for num in numbers) на my_list.extend(list(num for num in numbers)) получите аналогичный остальным вариантам результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_list.append(num for num in numbers)` работает так, как и должен. Вы пытаетесь в качестве аргумента методу `append` дать генератор - объект, который генерирует свое содержимое на лету в момент прочтения и не хранит его в памяти. До прочтения это лишь генераторный объект.
Если вы попробуете вместо него в качестве аргумента дать список `append([num for num in numbers])`, но тогда в ваш лист добавится этот список целиком, а не его значения. Распаковать его тоже не получится - в таком случае будет ошибка количества аргументов (`append` принимает только один, а вы подаете несколько). Ну и метод `extend` тоже работает как нужно - он расширяет ваш список **элементами** другого списка-аргумента, добавляя их в конец